# 1990s novella - Disease called X, causes intense lust, then death

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, sexuality

In the early 1990s or late 80s in *Asimov's* I read a novella-length story about a disease that was both sexually transmitted and caused intense lust - the disease was called "X" in common parlance.  Families hid the cause of death of afflicted relatives and late night hosts used the disease as a frequent punchline.  If I recall correctly, the main plot was about a disease researcher who succumbed to the disease.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

["Things of the Flesh"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41849), a novelette by [L. Timmel Duchamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._Timmel_Duchamp), published in [*Asimov's Science Fiction*, January 1994](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57277), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_n18n01_1994-01/page/n131/mode/2up).

It's not clear that the mysterious illness is transmitted sexually:

> The battle won't be merely the disease, but public attitudes toward it. . . . Somehow, mutations of "morally neutral" diseases (which is a stupid
> term, since it adopts the fundamentalists' frame of reference, but that is
> what we're talking about here), though causing grief and fear and pain,
> don't provoke outrage and irrational behavior. But X, alas, isn't "morally
> neutral." The weird thing about that, though, is that the disease isn't
> transmitted sexually (as far as we've been able to make out), but is
> "immoral" because of its symptoms. Which is a bizarre, chiasmatic
> switch.

The effects are as you described:

> While I was there I kept wondering about that window that apparently
> opens between the time patients begin focusing on sexual gratification
> and when they switch off entirely. Michael's deposition describing the
> onset of Celia Willis's sexual fugue (a term that Michael uses to describe
> the state of the X patients' not being present to the world) gives us a
> fairly close look at that window. At the bakery she was in touch enough
> to make contact with a possible sexual partner, but shortly thereafter
> was barely together enough to get him to the motel. (We'll probably
> never know whether she ever intended to have a drink with him first.)
> And then, very rapidly, she began to lose control. So that by the time
> her partner left, she was too far gone to think of finding a replacement,
> and so resorted, simply, to masturbation.
>
> It seems obvious that in the cases in which couples, the members of
> which are both stricken, are found in bed together in sexual fugue, they
> somehow remain aware enough of one another's bodies to be able to
> continue sexual activity, though without any more awareness of other
> sorts of inputs than any other of the patients in sexual fugue. Which
> horrifies me, somehow, more than the thought of so many people being
> found alone, masturbating unceasingly. (Or even more than the few cases
> of men reacting with sexual aggression: a kind of solipsistic violence that
> is in other contexts quite commonplace.) I imagine these couples, both
> their members stricken with X, fortuitously together at the onset of the
> sexual fugue, in that brief window, fucking without real awareness of
> what they're doing, like machines programmed to do an action until the
> power runs out. Fucking themselves to death.
>
> Creepy. But that's the scandal of it, that's so titillating to the media.
> (And frightening.) Of course so far the media believe its occurrence has
> been limited to this small backwoods area of a strange, traditionally odd
> state. . . .

Quotations are from the Personal Journal of Laurel di Sforza, M.D., who is investigating the disease, and succumbs to it in the end. From her last journal entry:

> This is it. I've got it. I've got X. Am so horny. Realized it when I couldn't bring myself to answer the phone, which has been chirping almost nonstop for two hours at least—because I was unwilling to stop masturbating. Explains why my period hasn't come. My hormones obviously a godawful mess. Oh the sexual fantasies, really wild. [. . .]